# How to add echo effect to wav file in android?

Tags: android, audio, android-ndk, echo, wav

I have been struggling for a while now on how to modify a wav file by adding echo effect on it; My app does pitch sifting, speed and volume, but I can't add effects. I'm a total begginer at audio engineering or something like that.

My main goal is to find an algorithm and make a function that takes the byte[] samples and modifies it.

```
I'm using this current code right now:



sonic = new Sonic(44100, 1);
            byte samples[] = new byte[4096];
            byte modifiedSamples[] = new byte[2048];
            int bytesRead;

            if (soundFile != null) {
                sonic.setSpeed(params[0]);
                sonic.setVolume(params[1]);
                sonic.setPitch(params[2]);
                do {
                    try {
                        bytesRead = soundFile.read(samples, 0, samples.length);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        return null;
                    }

                    if (bytesRead > 0) {
                        sonic.putBytes(samples, bytesRead);
                    } else {
                        sonic.flush();
                    }

                    int available = sonic.availableBytes();

                    if (available > 0) {
                        if (modifiedSamples.length < available) {
                            modifiedSamples = new byte[available * 2];
                        }

                        sonic.receiveBytes(modifiedSamples, available);
                        if (thread.getTrack() != null && thread.getTrack().getState() != AudioTrack.STATE_UNINITIALIZED)

                            thread.WriteTrack(modifiedSamples, available);
                    }

                } while (bytesRead > 0);
```

As you can see I use sonic ndk to alter the pitch speed and volume by passing another byte[] array there "modifiedSamples" and I need to know if there is a way to modify this "modifiedSamples" to get the echo effect. I know this sounds like I'm asking for the function, but I don't. I just don't know anything about audio processing stuff and I would apreciate a starting point or even if what i'm trying to do is possible with my byte array.

Comment: Check out [Sound Processing in Matlab](http://homepages.udayton.edu/~hardierc/ece203/sound.htm). It has info on how you can manipulate audio data - includes a simple algo of adding delay (echo) as well.

Comment: is this how the method should look? delayBuffer is my output byte[]    public void filter(byte[] samples) {

   delayBuffer=new byte[samples.length];
   int N=10000;
          
   for(int n = N+1; n< delayBuffer.length; n++){
    delayBuffer[n] = (byte) (samples[n]+samples[n-N]);
   }

  }  I get no sound :(

Comment: Yes your method looks fine, make sure that you don't overwrite the first 44 bytes of your wav file. I'll post the code in answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Continuing from the comments - here's an implementation that post-processes the wav file to add echo.

```
//Clone original Bytes
byte[] temp = bytesTemp.clone();
RandomAccessFile randomAccessFile = new RandomAccessFile(fileRecording, "rw");
//seek to skip 44 bytes
randomAccessFile.seek(44);
//Echo
int N = sampleRate / 8;
for (int n = N + 1; n < bytesTemp.length; n++) {
   bytesTemp[n] = (byte) (temp[n] + .5 * temp[n - N]);
}
randomAccessFile.write(bytesTemp);
```

The same process will work in real-time as well, with a few changes.

Comment: indeed I have an echo but how can I adjust it to be bigger? and another thing is that I have an hissing sound.

Comment: Glad it's working now. :) I myself am working on a sample project just now, to demonstrate real-time echo! When done, I'll post the link here. And regarding your question about the echo being bigger, remove the multiplication by .5 in the code above. Hopefully it'll also remove the hissing noise. If it doesn't then try changing different values for N.

Comment: what is sampleRate here ?? is it the same as input file ?

Comment: @sudo_rizwan did you end up posting the sample project? I'm interested in realtime audio processing like this, too.